# Running cron job in specific directory

Tags: cron

Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS non-GUI

I have a cron job set up as follows to take a screenshot of the desktop every 10 minutes at the below times on the hour.

```
0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * DISPLAY=:0 scrot
```

My question is scrot saves the image in the directory where the command is run from. How do I modify my cron job to tell it to save in to a specific directory (e.g. /tmp/screenshots/) or alternatively is there a way for me to tell scrot to run from a specific directory so it achieves the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there is a scrot-specific way to tell scrot where to save the files.

There is a way that works in general, for every command that acts based on its current directory. Instead of executing the command directly via cron, the command can be used in a shell script and cron just has to execute that script.

Your crontab would look like this:

```
0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * /home/hbkidf/bin/screenshot.sh
```

And the script could look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /tmp/screenshots/
DISPLAY=:0 scrot
```

To make this work, you have to set the executable flag on your script, e.g:

```
chmod u+x /home/hbkidf/bin/screenshot.sh
```

The script location (home directory, sub directory "bin") is just an example. The script might may be stored anywhere, as long as it is accessible for the user the cronjob is running as.

This script is just an extra layer between cron and scrot. This does not change anything related to the involved user(s). When the cronjob is running as User1, the script will be executed as User1, and thus scrot will be executed as User1.

Comment: Thanks Sheldon - whilst I'm running terminal only, I have a separate user running a visual program hence the requirement for screenshots.

I have the crontab set up on the separate user. Do I have to specify anything else to ensure the above is running on that specific user?

Comment: @hbkidf I added some clarification about the shell script.